# How to push down body and change its height?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to offset a body tag by some padding. However, I'd like to have the body adjusted so that it doesn't cause it to fall below the browser window and induce scrollbars.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/jM9Np/1/

**HTML:**

```
<body> </body>​
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;   
}

body {
 margin-top: 20em;
 background-color: LemonChiffon;
}
```

Ideally I'd like to subtract 20em from the body's height. Is there anyway to do this without any Javascript and in a manner that is supported by all browsers (with exception of Internet Explorer)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. You can use borders, f.ex:

```
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  border-top: 20em solid #fff;
  background-color: LemonChiffon;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jM9Np/10/

But the best way IMHO would be to add another DIV inside the body and position it absolute:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20em;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: LemonChiffon;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/za4e3/

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using your second block of code as this seemed most ideal to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting current versions of major browsers, you're lucky! This should work even on IE9 (see [full support table](http://caniuse.com/calc)):

```
html {
 height: 100%;   
}

body {
 margin-top: 20em;
 height: calc(100% - 20em); 
 background-color: LemonChiffon;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jM9Np/3/

Comment: The + and - operators must always be surrounded by whitespace

Comment: Wow, this is incredibly useful. Unfortunately it still seems to be pretty experimental (Opera doesn't support it yet?). Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @aziz.punjani MDN seems to agree with you, fixed :)

Comment: @user1669908 Yes, it's experimental and according to the [CSS3 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/) the feature may be dropped during the current "candidate recommendation" phase. But I really hope it doesn't!

Comment: @David That's only on jsfiddle. See this [example with a border](http://jsfiddle.net/jM9Np/11/)), or try with a local file and set the html bg to another color. Anyway, the options on your answer are the "traditional" way to deal with that, and thus more compatible. I only mentioned `calc` as the OP doesn't care about IE, so he might want to hear about the latest features...

Comment: @bfavaretto yes, it’s interesting in theory but I wouldn’t consider that support table to cover "all browsers except IE". Safari 5 and mobile browsers are not covered, f.ex.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
html{
height: 100%; 
background-color:black;
}
body {
height:80%;
margin-top: 20%;
background-color: LemonChiffon;
}
```

Comment: It can't be percentages. I need the measurements to be exact.